# How does Spock deal with equality of Mocked objects

Tags: unit-testing, groovy, spock

I am testing the behavior of class that uses a SortedSet of Library objects (regular class not an interface, so I have brought in cglib-nodep). I need to test the behavior of the class when the sorted set has multiple objects.  The Library objects have been mocked in this way:

```
Library library = Mock()
Library library2 = Mock()
```

Then, I create a TreeSet:

```
def libraries = [library, library2] as TreeSet
```

and call the system under test method:

```
sut.doStuff(libraries).
```

When I debug this test, I see that libraries is a SortedSet with just one element.  This seems to be a result of the way Spock deals with equality, as:

```
def "equality test"() {
    expect:
        library == library2
}
```

passes when I run the test.  Is there a way that I can get around this behavior?

EDIT: Changed = to == because I can't type

Comment: `library = library2` passed because it's an assignment not a comparison?

Comment: Yes, sorry about that, just a typing error, I didn't actually use the assignment in the test

Comment: Have you tried `library.is library2` instead? Not sure what `Library` is and how `equals()` and `hashCode()` or `compareTo()` is implemented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did some research. Have a look at the following set of tests (groovy console script):

```
@Grab('org.spockframework:spock-core:0.7-groovy-2.0')
@Grab('cglib:cglib-nodep:3.1')

import spock.lang.*

class Test extends Specification {
    def "not comparable mocks are not equal"() {
        given:
        def a1 = Mock(A)
        def a2 = Mock(A)

        expect:
        a1.hashCode() != a2.hashCode()
        !a1.equals(a2)
        !(a1 == a2)        
    }

    def "comparable mocks are not equal"() {
        given:
        def a1 = Mock(AC)
        def a2 = Mock(AC)

        expect:
        a1.hashCode() != a2.hashCode()
        !a1.equals(a2)
        !(a1 == a2)        
    }

    def "cannot create TreeSet when POJOs are not comparable"() {
        given:
        def a1 = Mock(A)
        def a2 = Mock(A)

        and:    
        a1.hashCode() != a2.hashCode()
        !a1.equals(a2)
        !(a1 == a2)     

        when:
        new TreeSet([a1,a2])

        then:
        def e = thrown(ClassCastException)
        e.message.endsWith('cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable')
    } 

    def "there's a problem with Comparable Mocks"() {
         given:
        def a1 = Mock(AC)
        def a2 = Mock(AC)

        and:    
        a1.hashCode() != a2.hashCode()
        !a1.equals(a2)
        !(a1 == a2)     

        when:
        def s = new TreeSet([a1,a2])

        then:
        s.size() == 2
    }

    def "with HashSet it works as expected"() {
        given:
        def a1 = Mock(AC) 
        def a2 = Mock(AC) 

        and:    
        a1.hashCode() != a2.hashCode()
        !a1.equals(a2)
        !(a1 == a2)     

        when:
        def s = new HashSet([a1,a2])

        then:
        s.size() == 2
    }
}

class A {}

class AC implements Comparable {

    int compareTo(Object o) {
        1 //whatever value may be here, it's not called
    }
}
```

In general there's a problem with when an object implements `Comparable` interface.

1. The first test shows that different mocks of the same objects have different hash codes and are not equal. According to me this is expected behavior.
2. The second test checks the same conditions except the fact that objects are `Comparable`. It fails. According to me this is not an expected behavior.
3. The third test illustrates that it's not possible to create a `TreeSet` with POJOs that are not comparable. Expected behavior.
4. The fourth test illustrates the problem mentioned by You. Size of a `TreeSet` created with of two `Comparable` mocks is expected to be 2. It fails, the size is 1.
5. The fifth test shows that the conditions from the 4 test are fulfilled when `HashSet` is used.

IMO this is not a `spock`-related problem. Spock uses `cglib` for mockin objects an this is where the explanation should be looked for.

**EDIT**

It works fine if `compareTo()` method is overridden for mock objects:

```
@Grab('org.spockframework:spock-core:0.7-groovy-2.0')
@Grab('cglib:cglib-nodep:3.1')

import spock.lang.*

class Test extends Specification {

    def "there's a problem with Comparable Mocks"() {
         given:
        def a1 = Mock(AC) {
            compareTo(_) >> 3145
        }
        def a2 = Mock(AC) {
            compareTo(_) >> 3146
        }

        and:    
        a1.hashCode() != a2.hashCode()
        !a1.equals(a2)
        !(a1 == a2)     

        when:
        def s = new TreeSet([a1,a2])

        then:
        s.size() == 2
    }
}

class AC implements Comparable {

    int compareTo(Object o) {
        1 //whatever value may be here, it's not called
    }
}
```

Comment: I do not believe that this is a cglib issue. Cglib will always delegate the invocation of the `compareTo` method. It is the delegation implementation that breaks the code and this is where one should probably look for a solution.

Comment: Don't know the implementation of cglib as well as spock well enough. It's just a shot bit thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Maybe Spock has a fallback where it renders `Comparable` mocks equal if the are comparable to each other. Mocked methods return `0` by default if not specified differently so I guess that a call of `library.compareTo(library2) == 0`. In this context, the equality test behaves right. Or maybe Groovy objects behave like this? I'm not really a Groovy guy.

Comment: I've tried to mock the `compareTo` method it was always returning `0` :/

Comment: It should not. I just tried it in cglib directly and it works fine.

Comment: Ok, so it seems that there's a problem with spock. Maybe I'll file an issue on GitHub later on.

Comment: Your edit worked, thank your for your assistance here.  The class originally implemented Comparable, so that may have been where the issue arose from.  Thanks for the workaround while you file an issue!

Comment: You're welcome. I haven't filed any issue to spock team and not sure if it should be filed - if You think so, feel free to continue.

Comment: I'll probably put in an issue and see what the response is.  I'll update you if I hear anything.

Answer (score 4):

Unless its `equals()` method is stubbed, a `Mock()` only `equals()` itself. However, Groovy's `==` doesn't always mean `equals()`. For `Comparable`s, it means `c1.compareTo(c2) == 0`. Likewise, a `TreeSet` uses `compareTo()` rather than `equals` to determine equality. Potential solutions:

- Stub the mocks' `compareTo()` methods to return suitable values.
- Don't use a `TreeSet`.
- Use real objects that implement `compareTo` in a suitable way rather than mocks.

PS: Perhaps `Mock(Comparable)` and/or `Stub(Comparable)` should automatically implement `compareTo` in a fashion that is consistent with `equals()`. Can you file an issue for this?